# pass an object to T4 template

Tags: c#, .net, templates, t4

I have an object `u1` of type `User` class. User has an attribute `name`. How can I pass in `u1` to a T4 template ? I am trying to do something very simple:

```
User u1 = new User("John");
```

Template script:

```
Hello <# u1.Name #>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you wanna use it in your template? Then you need to add a reference to the assembly containing the type. You cannot simply pass existing reference to the T4 engine unless you host it yourself in some highly unorthodox fashion (I've never seen anyone atempting to do this). And even if you went as far and did that how would you run it? Where is this reference supposed to come from?

Using the type from within a T4 template is as easy as adding the reference or copy/paste it in the class stub `<#+ /*stuff goes here*/ #>`.

Comment: I understand some of what you said, but could you please expand on this: `You cannot simply pass existing reference to the T4 engine unless you host it yourself` ? Also, just want you to know, both the .tt file and user class are a part of the same solution

Comment: Right. Well there's no way to hand off the reference. The T4 template actually runs in it's own domain. For several reasons. If you host the T4 processing you should be able to pass a reference to the processing but that's not something I've seen anyone do before. You best bet would be to either reference an assembly with the stuff you wish to utilize or add it, as part of the T4 class stub. Oleg Sych blogs about T4, look there for details on how to do this http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-assembly-directive/

Answer (score 3):

We did something similar to this. Our solution has the following elements:

- Custom host
- Custom template base class ("inherits" property of template directive)
- Host specific templates ("hostspecific" property of template directive)

The custom host is aggregated by the object which the stencil itself wants to invoke methods on.

```
interface ICallbackInterface
{
    void CallbackFxn();
}

[Serializable]
public class MyCustomHost : ITextTemplatingEngineHost, ITextTemplatingSessionHost, IStencilFileRecordManagement
{

    private ICallbackInterface callback = null;
    public MyCustomHost(ICallbackInterface cb)
    {
        callback = cb;
    }

    public void CallbackFxn()
    {
        callback.CallbackFxn();
    }
}

public abstract class MyTemplateBase : TextTransformation
{
    public virtual MyCustomHost CustomHost
    {
        get
        {
            dynamic metame = this;
            MyCustomHost rval = null;
            try
            {
                /// <summary>
                /// The "Host" property will be added to the generated class by the T4 environment whenever a 
                /// "hostspecific" template is processed. 
                /// </summary>
                rval = metame.Host as MyCustomHost;
            }
            catch (RuntimeBinderException e)
            {
                logger.ErrorException(
                    "Received the following exception while processing a stencil template", e);

            }
            return rval;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, within any of our templates, we can invoke methods on the object who actually kicked off the processing using the custom host property, eg:

```
<# CustomHost.CallbackFxn(); #>
```

Also, we don't use T4 in VS or using a separate executable -- we link against the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.10.0 and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interfaces.10.0 assemblies.

EDIT

We're using T4 templates allow users to define their own plugins for use in a particular step in our product workflow. So user templates are uploaded to our system, and processed like this:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating;

class UserPluginWorkflowComponent : ICallbackInterface
{
    public void CallbackFxn()
    {
        // invoked by user plugin
    }

    public void ExecuteUserPlugin()
    {
        MyCustomHost host = new MyCustomHost(this);
        host.TemplateFileValue = "UserPluginTemplateFilename";
        Engine engine = new Engine();
        string pluginResult = engine.ProcessTemplate(
            userPluginTemplateFileContents, 
            host);            
        if (!host.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            // use pluginResult in some meaningful way
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please expound a bit? Show how an objects "kicks off the processing"?

Answer (score 1):

T4 templates process in one step which so the template needs to get everything it needs during its run there for you don't really "Pass" anything into them. Since the Template is text I will generally just have some parameters the developer can set at the top of the file.  If you need user input you can have a window popup but man that sounds annoying when generating code.

Another solution is to use a custom template that uses template substitution in your t4 template similar to how a lot of the installed templates work.

Comment: As you can tell, I'm just starting and a lot in the dark. But, eventually, what I'd like to do is, create a compiled object of the template with references to an object of type user. When the template is finally `run`, it would use the properties of the object to output the text.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to have code in some application or tool that eventually runs the template, then using runtime (preprocessed) templates with either custom properties defined in a <#+ #> class feature block or the <#@ parameter #> directive should give you what you want.

Have a look at the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586944.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. We decided to not use T4, since it limited us to either use the host VS environment or invoking an external exec for the T4 engine. Scale was our primary concern and invoking external exec per call, is a very operation we couldn't afford. Please let me know if there is a workaround to this, since I really liked the power of T4 and perfectly fits the bill for what we are doing, but is limiting us in that context.

Comment: Preprocessed tempaltes don't require host VS.  If your template text is fixed at build time, they should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hey - You need to set values etc inside the T4 script, so the `User` initialization must happen inside the `<# #>` tag, which would turn you example into something similar to

```
     <# User u1 = new User() { .Name = "John" } #>
     Hello <# u1.Name #>
```

As mentioned above you may also need to import namespaces. I have used the statements below in the start of a TT-file to get access to System.Data:

```
     <#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
     <#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
     <#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
```